# How does combat work in Fury of Dracula

Tags: fury-of-dracula

In the rules for Fury of Dracula after resolving combat cards it says players refresh hands. I understand how this works for Dracula redrawing a new fifth combat card, what is unclear to me is how this applies to hunter players. Does this mean hunters gain a new copy of the default 3 hunter combat cards? Or do they take back the combat card they played assuming the resolved combat doesn't force it to be discarded?

Comment: Which edition? It works differently in all of them :)

Comment: @Pod I think probably 3rd edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** - At the start of combat you add 3 Combat cards to your hand (1 Dodge, Punch, and Escape). The end of each combat round you pick up any cards played in previous rounds of combat, not including the current rounds cards. Finally, once combat ends you remove the 3 combat cards (1 Dodge, Punch, and Escape) from your hand.

## Combat ( in short ) Works Like This:

> **Pre-Combat** The hunter takes **1 Dodge, Punch, and Escape** card from the hunter
>   combat card piles and adds them to his hand of item cards (these do
>   not count toward his hand limit).
>
> **1.** Each player chooses 1 card from his hand and places it facedown. The
>   hunter must choose one of his cards that has a banner (red or yellow).

Combat happens, players reveal and finally step 8:

> **8. Refresh Hands:** Dracula draws the top card of the Dracula combat deck. Combat cards played during this round remain in front of the
>   hunter who played it. Hunter combat cards played during the previous
>   round are returned to their owner's hand.

This limits the hunters options on what they can play if combat continues.

Anything played in this round of combat **will not be available** to play in the next round of combat.

Anything played in a previous round of combat is **now available** to be played in the upcoming round of combat ( if there is more combat to be had ).

Finally, if combat is finished you simply remove the 3 combat cards from your hand ( 1 Dodge, Punch, and Escape ):

> After combat ends, each hunter in the combat places his hunter combat
>   cards (Dodge, Punch, and Escape) back in the combat card piles near
>   the board. Dracula shuffles all Dracula combat cards into his deck.

[Rules on BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/133298/universal-head-fury-dracula-3rd-edition-rules-summ)

Comment: Does this mean that for Dracula's mesmerize card the hunter is only mesmerized for the next round of combat? assuming mesmerize is successful of course

Comment: Mesmerize only works on the current round of combat. Cards are revealed, we first see if the Hunter's card negates Mesmerize (Symbol check). If the Hunter did not cancel Mesmerize then Mesmerize occurs and cancels the Hunters card effect. If Mesmerize is cancelled then the Hunters card resolves as normal. All of this will happen during the current round of combat, not future rounds.

Comment: Sorry perhaps I phrased that poorly. I meant for Dracula's mesmerize effect on bite, if I recall bite when played against a mesmerized hunter adds a bite mark and has another extra effect. Is this limited to only the next round after mesmerize is played? Doesn't mesmerize also have a damage reducing effect when successful, how long does that last?

Comment: The Mesmerize effect only applies during that round of combat but is kept in front of the Hunter during the entire phase of combat. Other cards ( such as Fangs which I believe is what you're referring to ) can use Mesmerize to enhance it's effect. So, Mesmerize is kept in front of the Hunter during the entire combat phase but it's Mesmerize effect only happens during the round it's played.

Comment: I think this doesn't explain clearly that vampire's played cards are never picked up during combat, only Hunter gets his/her cards back after a round.